# iTunes -- making a shortened version of a sound

Tags: itunes, sound-editing

I have an m4A file.  I want to make a version of it that does not include the first second of the file.

If I right click on it and set the start time to 1 second, I can play it without that first second.  But how do I make a copy that does not have the first second at all?

Thanks

Comment: There should be a create AAC version or something of that sort - that will abide by the start time timings

Answer (score 3):

@devanjedi's answer gives you more granular control, but you can in fact do this in iTunes alone.

After you adjust the start time, go to the Advanced menu, or right click, and choose "Create AAC Version," (If you have iTunes set to import CDs into a different format, this will reflect that—as such, you can use iTunes to generate AIFFs, Mp3s, and WAV files as well.)

The resulting track will only contain the music between your start and end times.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get audio editing software (e.g. Audacity: http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)
2. Import the m4a file that you want to edit
3. You can edit it the way you would edit text- select the portion you want to remove (all but the first 1 second) and select "Export Selection as MP3" from the File menu. [this works in Audacity, other software will have similar options]
   This is your copy, without the first 1 second.